# Swift NSNotificationCenter add observer func in other class

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

I have `ViewContoller`, download class and class for work with data
in `ViewContoller` need call method for download data from internet, after `NSNotificationcenter` send complete message, and work class with data, after in my table I use reload data

Problem - `notifCenter.postNotificationName("completeLoadService", object: complete) Thread1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code = 1, address = 0x10)`

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    ServicesLoad.loadServicesFromSite()

    let center : NSNotificationCenter = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()

    var load : LoadServiceTrainersAreasClubs = LoadServiceTrainersAreasClubs()

    center.addObserver(load, selector: Selector("loadService:"), name: "completeLoadService", object: nil)
}
```

download class

```
        operation.setCompletionBlockWithSuccess({
        (operation : AFHTTPRequestOperation!, servicesData : AnyObject!) -> Void in

       //some code

            var complete  : Bool = Bool()
            complete = true

            var notifCenter : NSNotificationCenter = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
            notifCenter.postNotificationName("completeLoadService", object: complete)

        })
```

class work with data LoadServiceTrainersAreasClubs

```
func loadService(notif : NSNotification){

    println("complete")

}
```

Answer (score 1):

LoadServiceTrainersAreasClubs is a local variable. You do not have a strong reference to it. It will be deallocated as soon as the viewDidLoad method exits. NSNotificationCenter keeps observers as weak references. Therefore, it looks like NSNotificationCenter is attempting to notify your configured observer, but it has been deallocated which is causing the crash.

Also, I would recommend against using notification center for something like this. I would suggest using a block or delegate to inform the consumer of this service completion.

Comment: The variable is named `load`, `LoadServiceTrainersAreasClubs` is the type. But your conclusion is right: the object is deallocated by the time the notification is delivered. But why would it be a bad idea to use the notification center "like this"?

Comment: NSNotificationCenter is overused in my opinion for simple 1 to 1 relationships. It's an observer design pattern solution, which in general is used for 1 to many relationships. It can lead to confusion, and blocks/closures used as a callback mechanism encourage more readable code.

Comment: For 1:1 relationships I totally agree with you, that's what the delegate pattern is for.